# Not inserting Turkish characters in SQL table. Displays 'xxx??xxx' when selected

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, collation

I am trying to add Turkish names on my table but then when displayed it gives me ? instead of any of them. Any help what I am missing here? This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offerings` (
  `dep` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `section` varchar(3) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `teacher` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `quota` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec1` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec2` varchar(35) CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec3` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec4` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec5` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16;
```

As suggested from the answer I choose here is the solution to the problem for whoever googles this topic. Special thanks to all who contributed in the solution of my problem.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offerings` (
  `dep` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `grade` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `section` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `teacher` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quota` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `lec1` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec2` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec3` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec4` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lec5` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL   
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Are you sure the data that is inserted in the database is proper UTF-16? Make sure every part in the chain (from user input to storing in database)  uses the proper encoding.

Comment: I am using java to insert data. As far as I know java uses utf16

Comment: Are you able to set and display turkich chars with another software, like mysql workbench ?

Comment: I haven't used any software like that. I am using the command line. And also phpmyadmin. They both display 'xxx???xxx'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Beginnings of an answer...)

Please don't use utf16; there is virtually no reason for such in a MySQL table.

So, assuming you switch to utf8, let's see if we can get rid of the `?` problems.

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.  (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

What probably happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

Since the `CHARACTER SET` disagrees with what you have shown, the problem is possibly more complex.  Please provide

```
 SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

for some simple cell with Turkish characters.  With this, I may be able to figure out what happened.

Also, [Reference notes on encodings](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#turkish).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess this was my problem. IK the engine makes no difference but I decided to use MyISAM because I have been using it for so long.

Comment: True, the Engine makes no difference.  (However, InnoDB is the preferred engine for various reasons.)

Comment: Can you please tell me what reasons?

Comment: See [_Why InnoDB is preferred_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#why_innodb_is_preferred)

Comment: Thanks I got it. InnoDB look like the real thing. Still I don't care much about these properties as my table will have at most 2000 lines and I can remake it any time if it crushes. Plus I need the space more than the properties so my choice is better having small footprint. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

VARCHARs are character strings, while NVARCHARS are Unicode character strings.  NVARCHARS require more bits per character to store, but have a greater range.  Try updating your data types.  This should fix your problem.

**EDIT** This answer is wrong.  The OP clearly asked for a MySQL solution, but the above applies only to SQL Server.

Comment: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_turkish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `teacher` nvarchar(' at line 5"
~~
I just changed from varchar to nvarchar!! And I also used nvarchars if you think it should have been like that

Comment: Apologies I've given you a SQL Server answer, for a MySQL question.

Comment: I understand. Do you have any idea about my MySQL problem?